# Array printing too many times

Tags: java, arrays

My array is printing as many times as the index its in as well as null for example

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

I'm trying to print the array line by line through a text file that has 20 rows of 4 pieces of data.

I've tried moving the print statement outside of the while loop and that only displays the array in one long line.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to my program. ");

    System.out.println("This Program will read and display a text file in an array");
    String[] arr;
    try
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        arr = new String[50];//
        int i = 0;
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            arr[i++] = line;
            System.out.println(i + "." + Arrays.toString(arr) + "\n");
        }
        br.close();

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to print just the array element within your `while` loop rather than the whole array. For example: `while(...) { arr[i] = line; System.out.println(i + "." + arr[i]); i++; }`

Comment: Firstly, why do you even need an array here? If your objective is to print out the file contents, you can simply read/print line by line. If you need to use the array later, then it probably isn't important that the print outs are wrong (since the array is correct, less the starting index).

Answer (score 0):

Change this part.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    arr[i] = line; // was changed to arr[i] from arr[i++]
    System.out.println(i + "." + arr[i++] + "\n"); // was changed to arr[i++] from arr
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use on `Arrays.toString()` on `arr[i++]`. Just print it directly.

Comment: My mistake, I missed that. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
 {
    arr[i] = line;
    System.out.println(i + "." + arr[i++] + "\n");
  }
```

output would be ;
0. 1 12 123 1234 12345  // 0. is index